# Jenkins set value for environment variable from one stage to be used in another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have an environment var with default value

```
RUN_TESTS= true
```

My Jenkins job contains two stages, build and test stage.
The test stage modified to run 2 kind of tests sets depended on RUN_TESTS value.

RUN_TESTS value is set on build stage.

Is there a way to update value for environment variable for future use ?

Here what I tried without success

```
env.RUN_TESTS= true
node("node1"){
    sh '''
    printenv
    RUN_TESTS="false"
    '''
}
print RUN_TESTS
```

I am getting

```
+ RUN_TESTS=false
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
true
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

When you issue a `sh` directive, a new instance of shell (most likely `bash`) is created. As usual Unix processes, it inherits the environment variables of the parent. Notably, this includes `RUN_TESTS` variable and its value. So a copy of Jenkins environment variable `RUN_TESTS` is created for `sh` directive.

Your `bash` instance is then running your script. When your script sets or updates an environment variable, the environment of `bash` is updated. Once your script ends, the `bash` process that ran the script is destroyed, and all its environment is destroyed with it. Notably, this includes your updated `RUN_TESTS` variable and its value. This has no influence on the Jenkins environment variable `RUN_TESTS` that had its value copied before.

Here's a Python example demonstrating the same concept:

```
>>> def foo(i):
...     print(i)
...     i += 1
...     print(i)
...
>>> i = 6
>>> i
6
>>> foo(i)
6
7
>>> i
6
```

The variable `i` internal to function `foo` was first initialized to 6, then incremented to 7, then destroyed. The outer variable bearing the same name `i` was copied for the invocation of `foo` but wasn't changed as a result.

Comment: While all of this is well explained, it doesn't really answer the OP's question ...

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this

```
String RUN_TESTS = "true"

node("node1"){
    sh '''
    printenv
    RUN_TESTS = "false"
    '''
}
print RUN_TESTS
```